# ¿Cómo contar palabras en un vector de caracteres?

Tags: c

El ejercicio pide un vector de caracteres Z con una frase. Mostrar la cantidad de palabras. 
Entonces conté los espacios existentes en el arreglo, pero eso no contempla a la primera palabra. Para la última palabra conté el '.'. Lo hice así:

```
int Z[50];
int palabras;
for (int i=0;i<50;i++){
  if (z[i]==' ' || z[i] == '.')
     palabras++;
}
```

Hay otra forma para considerar la primera y última palabra de la frase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu idea de contar los espacios y puntos para determinar la cantidad de palabras tiene varios problemas, si comenzamos o terminamos la frase con un espacio o punto, o si hay más espacios entre palabras, en cualquier caso estaremos contando de más.

Lo que deberías hacer es considerar los espacios y los puntos como separadores (podríamos agregar cualquier otro caracter) y usarlos para ir sumando una palabra siempre que el caracter anterior no sea un "separador" es decir sea una palabra. Algo como esto:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char z[50]=" Un ejemplo, veamos cuantas palabras cuenta. ";
    int palabras=0;
    int es_palabra=0;

    for (int i=0;(i<50 && z[i]!=0);i++){
        if (z[i]!=' ' && z[i] != '.') {
          es_palabra = 1;
        } else {
          if (es_palabra == 1) {
              palabras++;
              es_palabra = 0;
          }
      }
    }
    /* Si el último caracter es de un palabra no olvidar sumarlo */
    if (es_palabra == 1)
        palabras++;

    printf("La frase \"%s\" tiene %d palabras\n", z, palabras);
    return 0;
}
```

Notas:

- En tu ejemplo has denominado de dos formas distintas el array `Z`, recuerda que **C** es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.
- No olvides inicializar las variables, en **C** no hay valores iniciales,  al hacer esto `int palabras;` e intentar usar `palabras` sin inicalizar obtendrás cualquier valor.

Comment: Gracias por tus observaciones. Me queda una duda...cada vez que no es un espacio o un punto supone que está en una palabra e incrementa la variable. Pero en ese caso, no estaría contando la cantidad de letras?

Comment: @Adri, el contador de palabras recién va a sumar 1 cuando encuentre un espacio o un punto pero solo luego de cualquier caracter que no sea alguno de estos, la única salvedad es que al salir del ciclo hay que ver si el último caracter corresponde a una palabra hay que sumarla al total